# When I press play a gameobject disappears

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am creating a FPS game in Unity and have a gun attached to the firstpersoncamera from the Standard Assets, that worked fine until now, when I press the Play button in the editor the gun disappears.

I followed all the steps [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/306574/objects-disappear-on-play.html) and it still disappears.

I'm very new to making games with Unity so I probably missed something obvious.

This is the code:

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;

    public class PlayerShooting : MonoBehaviour {

    public ParticleSystem muzzleFlash;
    Animator anim;
    public GameObject impactPrefab;

    GameObject[] impacts;
    int currentImpact = 0;
    int maxImpacts = 5;

    bool shooting = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        impacts = new GameObject[maxImpacts];
        for(int i = 0; i < maxImpacts; i++)
            impacts[i] = (GameObject)Instantiate(impactPrefab);

        anim = GetComponentInChildren<Animator> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if(Input.GetButtonDown ("Fire1") && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            muzzleFlash.Play();
            anim.SetTrigger("Fire");
            shooting = true;
        }

    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if(shooting)
        {
            shooting = false;

            RaycastHit hit;

            if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hit, 50f))
            {
                if(hit.transform.tag == "Enemy")
                    Destroy (hit.transform.gameObject);

                impacts[currentImpact].transform.position = hit.point;
                impacts[currentImpact].GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().Play();

                if(++currentImpact >= maxImpacts)
                    currentImpact = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I made a GameObject called Pistol, that is a child of the camera of the  First person Controller, ive created a canvas with an image so that i have a croshair and, i made some animations for the pistol, a reload animation that should work when you pres "r" and a shoot animation, and a sprint animation, the sprint animation worked until the gun stopped displaying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it, changed the Depth of the GunCamera to 1 instead of 0 and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

[image]GameObject via GameObject->Create Empty and name it
Now this should be attached as child of the Main Camera 
Now this Main Camera isnt the deault main camera but the main camera present inside your First person Controller object that you added.

Any screenshot or sample code would have helped in finding the exact error

Comment: how do you post an image?

Comment: I have edited my answer and my mousepointer points to the option that allows uploading of pic Press Ctrl+PrintScreen on the screen that you wantr to share and on the Dialog that opens up press Ctrl+v and ur pic would be uploaded

Comment: You need at least 10 reputation, i just created my account so im posting it on imgur

Comment: Sorry hadnt seen your reputation. The problem with the pic is we would need one where you have selected your Main camera with right panel showing its properties and one where you have selected its child game object with right panel showing properties

Comment: Since its a test project sharing the sample code if possible will also help